# Problems running a servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am having problems with my Servlet. When I execute the code in Apache Tomcat, it returns this message:

```
type Informe de estado (status report)
mensaje /certificacion/ch1/Serv1
descripción El recurso requerido no está disponible. (Not available resource)
```

My code is simple. The xml contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the Servlet contains:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        out.println("<html> "+"<body>"+"<h1 align=center>Chapter1 Servlet</h1>"+"<br>"+today+"</body>"+"</html>");
    }
}
```

The folder structure is:

```
--tomcat
  ->webapps
    ->certificacion
      ->ch1
        ->WEB-INF
          ->web.xml
          ->classes
            ->Ch1Servlet.class
```

The example is taken from the book "Head First Servlets & JPS" page 31.

Can you help me?

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to access?

Comment: Did you add servlet to web.xml?

Comment: The URL should be `/ch1/Serv1`, not `/certificacion/ch1/Serv1`. Why are you learning servlets with version 2.4? The current version is 3.1. 2.4 is very old.

Comment: If your servlet is in a package, then please specify that packagename with servrlet in servletclass tag like <servlet-class>packagename.Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>

Comment: @anptk But the code does not contain an `package ...` statement

Comment: Sorry @JBNizet i forget to include certificacion in folder structure. I am learning version 2.4 because the book was wrote for this version.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the url is http://localhost:8090/certificacion/ch1/Serv1 (i changed my apache port to 8090)

Comment: @msrd0 do you think that problem is caused for not contain an package?

Comment: @anptk the book does not indicate to must specify an packagename

Comment: You package structure is wrong. It was correct initially, but the URL as wrong. The WEB-INF directory must be at the root of the webapp.

Comment: Thank you so much at all. The correct answer is that my package structure was wrong. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the application is deployed in root context try
host:port/Serv1

or this would work
host:port/certification/Serv1

Answer (score 1):

Your folder structure is wrong. It must be like this:

```
--tomcat
  ->webapps
    ->certificacion
      ->WEB-INF
        ->web.xml
        ->classes
          ->Ch1Servlet.class
      ->ch1
```

Then, if you want the Servlet to be accessed like

```
http://localhost:8080/certification/ch1/Servlet
```

than you need to add/change your `web.xml` file to contain this:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Chapter 1 Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Ch1Servlet
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Chapter 1 Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ch1/Servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```